# C# UWP reading serial data throws exception

Tags: c#, gps, raspberry-pi3, uart, windows-10-iot-core

So I found a way to read serial data from the UART channel, using windows 10 iot core. Now, I get some data spit out, but, it crashes like instantly and returns `Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll`.

The code I use to get the data:

```
private async Task read_gps_data(string port = "UART0", int baud = 9600)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                        {
                            string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("UART0");                   /* Find the selector string for the serial device   */
                            var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);                    /* Find the serial device with our selector string  */
                            SerialDevice SerialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);    /* Create an serial device with our selected device */

                            /* Configure serial settings */
                            SerialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                            SerialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                            SerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;                                             /* mini UART: only standard baudrates */
                            SerialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;                                  /* mini UART: no parities */
                            SerialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;                           /* mini UART: 1 stop bit */
                            SerialPort.DataBits = 8;

                            ///* Write a string out over serial */
                            //string txBuffer = "Hello Serial";
                            //DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter();
                            //dataWriter.WriteString(txBuffer);
                            //uint bytesWritten = await SerialPort.OutputStream.WriteAsync(dataWriter.DetachBuffer());

                            /* Read data in from the serial port */
                            const uint maxReadLength = 1024;
                            DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(SerialPort.InputStream);
                            uint bytesToRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(maxReadLength);
                            string rxBuffer = dataReader.ReadString(bytesToRead);
                            Debug.WriteLine(rxBuffer);
                            Debug.WriteLine("\n");
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

Now this code is found on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/pinmappings/pinmappingsrpi

The data it spits out:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Tripmaster.exe
,ANTSTATUS=OPEN*2B
$GPRMC,165556.000,A,5048.7305,N,00305.1325,E,0.00,109.81,270618,,,D*6F
$GPVTG,109.81,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,D*39
$GPGGA,165556.000,5048.7305,N,00305.1325,E,2,7,1.41,8.2,M,47.2,M,,*58
$GPGSA,A,3,20,27,10,32,22,14,08,,,,,,2.41,1.41,1.96*05
$GPGSV,4,1,13,08,73,179,27,18,68,282,,11,54,285,,01,42,274,*7F
$GPGSV,4,2,13,10,37,055,34,27,37,145,28,22,32,214,33,32,32,101,31*70
$GPGSV,4,3,13,28,27,312,,36,25,145,35,14,21,127,31,20,10,052,29*78
$GPGSV,4,4,13,03,09,217,15*41
$GPGLL,5048.7305,N,00305.1325,E,165556.000,A,D*53
$GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSTATUS=OPEN*2B
$GPRMC,165557.000,A,5048.7305,N,00305.1325,E,0.00,109.81,270618,,,D*6E
$GPVTG,109.81,T,,M,0.00,N,0.00,K,D*39
$GPGGA,165557.000,5048.7305,N,00305.1325,E,2,7,1.41,8.2,M,47.2,M,,*59
$GPGSA,A,3,20,27,10,32,22,14,08,,,,,,2.41,1.41,1.96*05
$GPGSV,4,1,13,08,73,179,26,18,68,282,,11,54,285,,01,42,274,*7E
$GPGSV,4,2,13,10,37,055,33,27,37,145,27,22,32,214,32,32,32,101,30*78
$GPGSV,4,3,13,28,27,312,,36,25,145,34,14,21,127,30,20,10,052,29*78
$GPGSV,


Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
```

I need to run this multi-threaded, since I need to update the GUI and store data and process data and get data from localstorage and display it. But that's out of the scope of this question. The issue here is, every second I got new GPS data, but it just crashes and I don't know why...

Comment: You might be reading faster than the GPS is sending.  Make sure there are bytes available before you read from the serial port.  I would also not set up the serial port over and over again inside a `while (true)` loop.  That will cause problems.

Comment: I was planning on putting it inside a class, but then I got problems with `SerialPort` as a not found in current context... Also, I have two await operators in there, so I don't know how to handle that... Beside that, It's possible that the device reads faster then it receives, is there a possibillity to sync them? Or to wait for the data and then read it?

Comment: @Naikrovek I fixed the class, so now I can call my data via a class and just request the data and not set up the device the whole time.

Answer (score 2):

'System.NullReferenceException' occurs at this line: `var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);` because you repeatedly call `SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("UART0");` but only first time you will get the UART0 device other you will get `null` result of `aqs`.

The right format is initialize the device one time and read date in a while loop. For example like this:

```
    private async void read_gps_data(string port = "UART0", int baud = 9600)
    {
            string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("UART0");                   /* Find the selector string for the serial device   */
            var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);                    /* Find the serial device with our selector string  */
            SerialDevice SerialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id);    /* Create an serial device with our selected device */

            /* Configure serial settings */
            SerialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            SerialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            SerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;                                             /* mini UART: only standard baudrates */
            SerialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;                                  /* mini UART: no parities */
            SerialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;                           /* mini UART: 1 stop bit */
            SerialPort.DataBits = 8;


            /* Read data in from the serial port */
            const uint maxReadLength = 1024;
            DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(SerialPort.InputStream);

            string rxBuffer = "";

            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        uint bytesToRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(maxReadLength);
                        rxBuffer = dataReader.ReadString(bytesToRead);
                        Debug.WriteLine(rxBuffer);
                        Debug.WriteLine("\n");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                    }

                    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                    {
                        // Update UI here
                        receivedData.text = rxBuffer;
                    });

                });

            }

    }
```

For example, you can call above function in a button click event to start the read operation:

```
Private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    read_gps_data();
}
```

Comment: I tried using your code (you missed `Task` or `void`), but then I got the same issue there. It gets data, but then it just crashes, isn't there a method to sync the device and listen for incomming data?

Comment: @Robin As far as I know the only method is waiting for data to arrived and no callback or event to notify. The code works for me. How do you call the read_gps_data() function and which line cause crash?

Comment: Okay, got it to work, but now all the other thread stop and the system goes really slow, isn't there a way to "wait" untill "all" data is received in a buffer and read every second the data?

Comment: @Robin Wait until all data will cause UI lose responsive in this time period. My suggestion is set the buffer big enough to receive the data send in one time(one second).

Comment: @Robin How many bytes send from sender one time or one second?

Comment: I don't know how many byted I get, but I know that I got a pulse of data every clock tick (every GPS second)

Comment: @Robin Because you mentioned you want to "wait" until "all" data in every second so figure out how many bytes sent in every GPS second should make sense, so you can receive complete data sent in one time. As for GPS data, it is fixed length or at least has a max length? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Well I have no clue.. what I get are NMEA messages , but I don't know how much that is....

Comment: @Robin You can check the GPS device datasheet.

Comment: It's an L80, but I can't find any sheet with how long the pulse is etc...